# Different 3d plots of (n,n,m) matrix : MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix a=360x360x2048

now I want to plot them in 3d

**My attempt**

```
x = 1:size(a,2);
y = 1:size(a,1);
z = 1:size(a,3);
```

How to plot this in 3d

Now I want to 3d plot this

**now I want to plot them all**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Slices of a Matrix to Create 3D Plot

Given that I saw the question before the multiple edits. Using the `slice()` function may help to plot the 3D matrix as slices in a 3D plot. The `slice()` function takes three additional inputs along with the matrix/volume to be plotted. The following three inputs dictate the method used to slice the matrix. In this example, slicing was done so that you can have a set of xy-planes that are stacked along the z-axis.

[image: Plotting Volume Matrix as Slices]

```
%Generating a random test array% 
X_Dimension = 360; Y_Dimension = 360; Z_Dimension = 5;
Volume = rand(X_Dimension,Y_Dimension,Z_Dimension);

%Configuring the slicing method%
X_Slice = [];
Y_Slice = [];
Z_Slice = 1:size(Volume,3);

%Plotting slices of array%
Slices = slice(Volume,X_Slice,Y_Slice,Z_Slice);
xlabel("x"); ylabel("y"); zlabel("z");

%Removing edge lines%
for Slice = 1: length(Slices)
Slices(Slice).EdgeAlpha = 0;
end

%Angle of 3D plot and colorbar%
Angle = 72; Elevation = 10;
view(Angle, Elevation);
colorbar
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `imagesc()` which only works in 2D, you could try to use `scatter()` and its 3D extension `scatter3()`.

```
nslices = 100;
nelems = 360;
A = rand(nelems, nelems, nslices); % your matrix

% Marker settings for scatter plot
mrkrSize = 10;
mrkr = '.';

figure
hold on
view(3)

for i = 1:nslices
    % Get the i-th matrix
    Aslice = A(:, :, i);

    idx = find(Aslice);
    [x, y] = ind2sub(size(Aslice), idx);
    z = i.*ones(size(x));

    scatter3(x, y, z, mrkrSize, Aslice(idx), 'Marker', mrkr);
end
```